# Transitions & multiple values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add a transition to my three buttons, but it seems not to work with my code. I tried to use the code snippet on `Vue.js` main page, but no good. Could someone please show an example or other sources I can find my answer? I'm also trying to have more than one `order_value` when someone presses one of the three buttons.

Here is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="b-template">
<div>
    <div>{{showText}}</div>
    <div id="drip">
    <button v-on:click="choose('Drip')">Drip</button>
    <button v-on:click="choose('Frenchpress')">French Press</button>
    <button v-on:click="choose('Aeropress')">Aeropress</button>
</div>
</script>
```

My JavaScript:

```
Vue.component("barista-template", {
    template: "#b-template",
    data: function() {
        return {
            user_order:"",
            computer:"",
            order_type:"",
            order_value: "",
        }
    },
    computed: {
        showText() {
            if(this.order_type === '') return '';
            return 'One ' + this.order_type + ' that would be ' + this.order_value
        }
    },
    methods: {
        choose: function (order_type) {
            this.order_type = order_type;

            if (this.user_order == "drip") {
                if (this.user_order == "drip") this.order_value = 5;
            }
            if (this.user_order == "frenchpress") {
                if (this.computerMove == "frenchpress") this.outcome ="French press";
            }
            if (this.user_order == "Aeropress") {
                if (this.computerMove == "Aeropress") this.outcome = "Aeropress";
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: I don't see `<transition>` tags anywhere. It's also not clear what kind of transition you want to do.

Comment: Sorry i was just trying to add a fade-enter and leave https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html